# cakePHP gives false error, [MissingComponentException] Component class cookieComponent

Tags: php, cakephp

I've just uploaded a new cakephp site and I'm getting the following error:

```
2014-01-19 18:17:07 Error: [MissingComponentException] Component class cookieComponent could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
'class' => 'cookieComponent',
'plugin' => false,
)
```

I did confirm that in the 'Lib' folder, the cookie component does exist, but I still get this message. Also, on my local wamp site I don't get the same error.

I did try removing the 'cookie' value from the app controller but then the whole site goes blank.

Other details include:
- cakephp version 2.9
- php 5.3

I have searched through other questions on stackoverflow but nothing stood out. If the component exists why would this error come up?

Thanks for the feedback, the missing upper case resolved that issue. Now two other issues have come up that don't make sense. From the tmp->error logs I get these:

```
Request URL: /fonts/webfonts/geo-medium/eot/1110FC_0.eot
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/content/l/e/d/ledesigns/html/app/webroot/index.php(108):     Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2014-01-20 08:21:39 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class     FontsController could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
'class' => 'FontsController',
'plugin' => NULL,
)
```

and

```
Request URL: /fonts/webfonts/geo-semibold/eot/style_169898.eot
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/content/l/e/d/ledesigns/html/app/webroot/index.php(108):   Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2014-01-20 08:21:39 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class CssController   could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
'class' => 'CssController',
'plugin' => NULL,
)
```

and

```
Request URL: /files/uploads/46-Bathroom_Spa_Door_400x569.jpg
Stack Trace:
 #0 /home/content/l/e/d/ledesigns/html/app/webroot/index.php(108): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2014-01-20 08:12:23 Error: [MissingComponentException] Component class cookieComponent     could not be found.
  Exception Attributes: array (
 'class' => 'FilesController',
 'plugin' => NULL,
```

)

I've never had errors calling for a fontscontroller, csscontroller or filescontroller. What's also odd is the jpg file mentioned above only existed in the previous site and was deleted when I uploaded the new site files?

Also, my local wamp files have none of these errors.

Really appreciate the feedback.

Comment: it seems like it is searching for cookieComponent instead of CookieComponent. are you moving the application from windows to a Linux based server?

Comment: "CakePHP" and "CookieComponent" both should start with a capital "C" :)

Comment: thanks, you're both correct. The missing upper case resolved that issue, but now two other issues came up. I've added details above.